# Don't close the modal when click on content with React.s

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I created a simple react modal but when i click modal content it also close it.

I have a wrapper div with class `modal_wrapper` which change background of body when modal is open and when i click anywhere in this div modal is closed.

But modal is also closed when i click anywhere of `modal_content` div.

**How can i stop closing the modal when i click inside `modal_content` div ?**

**[JSDFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8rsdgpvv/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop click event propagation.
In dont_close_modal function, capture the click event and then you can stop the propagation like this.

```
dont_close_modal:function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    this.setState({
    open_modal:true
  })
},
```